# MYSQL Transaction with procedure and if statement

Tags: sql, mysql

As part of an assignment using MYSQL, I wrote a procedure that updates a score and the icon associated with it from a table. As a last step, I must use a transaction with ROLLBACK and COMMIT to make sure that when a score greater than 100 or lower than 0 is given, the updates don't go through. However, when testing, the rollback doesn't kick into effect for out of bounds values like 101 or -5 and I don't know why. The hints, if I understood them correctly, suggested I put the COMMIT and ROLLBACK statements where I have placed them, but maybe that is not correct? Or what is the problem?

I give it an in_Leader_Score of 101 it should rollback without updating anything, or no? Below is the code

```
sql

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE (IN in_School_ID INT, IN in_Leader_Score INT)
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE chicago_public_schools
    SET Leaders_Score = in_Leader_Score
    WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    
    IF in_Leader_Score > 0 AND in_Leader_score < 20 THEN
    UPDATE chicago_public_schools
    SET Leaders_Icon = "Very weak"
    WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score < 40 THEN
    UPDATE chicago_public_schools
    SET Leaders_Icon = "Weak"
    WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score < 60 THEN
    UPDATE chicago_public_schools
    SET Leaders_Icon = "Average"
    WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score < 80 THEN
    UPDATE chicago_public_schools
    SET Leaders_Icon = "Strong"
    WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score < 100 THEN
    UPDATE chicago_public_schools
    SET Leaders_Icon = "Very strong"
    WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;

    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
            RESIGNAL;
        END;
     END;
    END IF;
    COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Looks like there is no logic that checks whether the score is less than 0 or greater than 100, hence your ROLLBACK will not be triggered. You have to explicitly set a condition to trigger a ROLLBACK.
- You've declared the EXIT HANDLER within an ELSE block, which means it will not be active for the rest of the transaction. The EXIT HANDLER needs to be declared at the beginning of the BEGIN block for the entire procedure so that it can capture exceptions throughout the entire procedure.

Try this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE (IN in_School_ID INT, IN in_Leader_Score INT)
BEGIN
    -- Declare an exit handler for any SQL exceptions
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        RESIGNAL;
    END;

    -- Start the transaction
    START TRANSACTION;

    -- Check for invalid scores
    IF in_Leader_Score < 0 OR in_Leader_Score > 100 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid score value. Must be between 0 and 100.';
    END IF;

    -- Update the score
    UPDATE chicago_public_schools
    SET Leaders_Score = in_Leader_Score
    WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;

    -- Update the icon based on the score
    IF in_Leader_Score >= 0 AND in_Leader_Score < 20 THEN
        UPDATE chicago_public_schools
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Very weak'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score < 40 THEN
        UPDATE chicago_public_schools
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Weak'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score < 60 THEN
        UPDATE chicago_public_schools
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Average'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score < 80 THEN
        UPDATE chicago_public_schools
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Strong'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score <= 100 THEN
        UPDATE chicago_public_schools
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Very strong'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    END IF;

    -- Commit the transaction
    COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```